# Blow-up of $\mathbb{P}^4$ along a smooth surface

Tags: birational-geometry, algebraic-surfaces, blow-ups, 4-manifolds

Let $\pi \colon X\to \mathbb{P}^4$ be the blow-up of a smooth surface $S\subset \mathbb{P}^4$. Is there a formula to compute $(K_X)^4$ ? (which should be dependent on invariants of $S$).

In dimension $3$, the formula is $(K_X)^3=62-8d+2g$, where $d$ is the degree of the curve and $g$ is its genus.

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/162839/top-self-intersection-of-exceptional-divisors

Comment: The cohomology algebra of a blow up can be described in a completely explicit way, see for instance Griffiths-Harris, pp. 605 and following. Getting from this the formula you are asking for is just a (somewhat lengthy...) exercise.